# Filter out array keys which are an integer

Tags: php, arrays

I have multiple arrays (which are all results from a MySQL database using a PDO statement), here is one as an example:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [0] => 1 [name] => HELLO [1] => HELLO )
```

I only want the keys which are not numbers (in this case 'id' and 'name') as the array.

How can I filter out the keys which are integers so that I can end up with an array which will be:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => HELLO )
```

(The keys aren't always going to be 'id' and 'name', or the name numbers, or the same number of array keys)

Comment: Maybe you can solve this problem with pdo. using `$stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`?

Comment: Just loop through the array.  What's stopping you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should solve this problem fetching row with appropriate flag [PDO::FETCH_ASSOC](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id,name FROM tableName");
$sth->execute();

$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // use this flag for return only column names
```

If it's not possible:

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v) {
    if(filter_var(FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $k) !== FALSE) {
        unset($array[$k]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newRow = array();
foreach($row as $key => $value)
    if(is_string($key))
        $newRow[$key] = $value;
```